# ExpressionEngine putting Javascript on a page

Tags: javascript, templates, expressionengine

I am a super beginner to EE and was literally thrust into managing my company's website that is built in EE without training. I'm not a programmer, I'm a designer, so it's been taking me awhile to plug through this. So I might need some dumbed down language :)

I want to create a page that has some Javascript on it. Do I need to create a new template JUST so I can put some javascript on it? And how do I communicate to EE that I want the page I created to go with that template?

I duplicated the page/index template and renamed it to clinician-map (the same name of the page I created in the publisher). EE didn't like that and the page subsequently broke. All I want to do is insert one javascript item, this seems way too inefficient for just one page. Help??

(using EE 1.6.8)
Here is my code from clinician-map template.

```
{assign_variable:my_weblog="page"}
{assign_variable:my_template_group="page"}

{embed="embeds/html_head" url_title="{segment_2}"}

{embed="embeds/html_styles"}

{embed="embeds/html_scripts"}

<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>

</head>
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="{my_weblog}" disable="categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" limit="1" sort="asc" }
<body class="{url_title}">
{/exp:weblog:entries}

<div id="wrapper">

    {embed="embeds/html_headerPlusLeftNav"}

 <div id="content">
        <div id="contentMain">

{exp:weblog:entries weblog="{my_weblog}" disable="categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" limit="1" sort="asc"}
<h2>{title}</h2>
{page_body}
{/exp:weblog:entries}



<!--contactforminfo -->






{exp:weblog:entries weblog="{my_weblog}" disable="categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"}
{related_entries id="playa_contentcalloutitems"}
<div class="callout">
<h3>{title}</h3>
{callout_summary}
</div>
{/related_entries}
{/exp:weblog:entries}


{exp:weblog:entries weblog="{my_weblog}" disable="categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"}
{related_entries id="playa_contentfeatureditems"}
<div class="featuredContent">
<h3>{title}</h3>
{exp:word_limit total="50"}
{contentfeatured_summary}
{/exp:word_limit}{if contentfeatured_body!=""}<p><a href='{url_title_path='content-featured/'}' class='more'>Read More</a></p>{/if}
</div>
{/related_entries}
{/exp:weblog:entries}



</div>


{exp:weblog:entries weblog="{my_weblog}" disable="categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"}    
<div id="contentSub">{related_entries id="playa_contentsubitems"}<div class="item   {contentsub_bgcolor}">

 {if contentsub_contenttype=="Text or Picture with Text"}
 <h3>{title}</h3>
{exp:word_limit total="50"}
{contentsub_summary}
{/exp:word_limit}{if contentsub_body!=""}<p><a href='{url_title_path='content-sub/'}' class='more'>Read More</a></p>{/if}

{if:else}

<h3 class="imgHeader">{title}</h3>
{exp:html_strip convert="y" convert_back="none" keep="a,img"}
{contentsub_summary}
{/exp:html_strip}

{/if}

</div>{/related_entries}
{/exp:weblog:entries}

{embed="embeds/html_mailingListSignup"}



        </div>

</div>



{embed="embeds/html_footer"}




</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To answer this, I think we need some more information. First, what sort of URL do you want the page to be at? `http://example.com/clinician-map/`? Second, are you using the Pages module at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I ended up just creating a new webblog and new template group and finally it seems like it's working. My javascript is not, but I can figure that out.

Thank you so much for your patience with helping me!

Answer (score 0):

At glance I can see a couple things that might be confounding you...

You started with a template called 'index' in the 'page' template group.

Looks like the 'page' template you are starting from is meant to display a single entry from the  'page' weblog.

So a request url might look something like this:

http://example.com/page/some_url_title

where 'some_url_title' is the 'url_title' value one of the entries in your 'page' weblog.

Now you have gone and duplicated the index template and called this new template 'clinician-map'.

So you would call an entry through this template at:

http://example.com/page/clinician-map/some_url_title

Now, notice that the first url had 2 segments, while the second had 3 segments?

That's not normally a big deal but the fellow who designed the index template did something that makes it problematic.  He is taking the value of segment_2 and passing it through an embed.

So in the first example (index) we are passing the dynamic value "some_url_tile" while in the second example (clinician-map) we are passing "clinician-map".  If the embedded template 'html_head' is expecting to get a valid url_title but instead gets the string 'clinician-map' you are likely going to get unexpected results.

Also I don't think we know enough about what you are trying to do to decide if creating a new template is the right approach here. It may be that what you actually need is a new weblog entry or perhaps just a dynamic value inside your existing template.

If it did turn out that a new template is the best approach you could fix the problem I have described by simply replacing segment_2 with segment_3, but I am by no means certain that that is the way you want to go.

Comment: I'm trying to install the Leaflet map system to the webpage.  I got it to work using the above code that Jarrett provided but my template (clinician-map) is not reading from my post (clinician-map). It's acting more like I "broke" the page rather than just giving me the page simply.

I tried changing it to segment_3 but it still does not work.

Comment: would you care to share a link?

Comment: This bit belongs in the body, not in the head: <div id="map"></div>

Comment: I can see raw php when I view your html source: <?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>. You want to enable PHP for the template for this to work.  But really it would be better moved into an EE template and called via an embed.

Comment: I removed it, but the site itself is still messed up. Good eye! I also moved the map calling and now it doesn't even show up. Expression Engine is a pain! haha

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a page that has some Javascript on it. Do I need to
>   create a new template JUST so I can put some javascript on it?

More specifics would be needed in order to give a solid recommendation but in almost every case, I recommend keeping JavaScript grouped together either in the <head></head> or ideally right before the closing </body> tag if you can get away with it.

Looking at your template code, it appears all the JavaScript is stored in the embeds/html_scripts page. I would add the JavaScript you need to that template. If you only want the JavaScript to appear for certain pages only, I would make use of a conditional (which I'll outline at the end of my answer).

> And how do I communicate to EE that I want the page I created to go
>   with that template?

ExpressionEngine URLs (by default) are assembled as follows:

http://website.com/group/template/url_title

Therefore if you have a page with a url_title of "contact-us", and you wanted that page to use a template in site/pages, you could tell your page to use that template like so:

http://website.com/site/pages/contact-us

That url is obviously fine and dandy for blog articles and such, but it's not that pretty; so  ExpressionEngine also enables you to construct "page" based navigation which creates navigation tree based url structures, such as:

http://website.com/contact-us

There are a few third party modules that make it easy to build page navigation such as:
devot-ee.com/add-ons/structure

Using Structure, you specify the default template for each channel and can override the template for each page as well.

> I duplicated the page/index template and renamed it to clinician-map
>   (the same name of the page I created in the publisher). EE didn't like
>   that and the page subsequently broke. All I want to do is insert one
>   javascript item, this seems way too inefficient for just one page.
>   Help??
>
> (using EE 1.6.8) Here is my code from clinician-map template.

There are a number of things I would do different in regards to the template code you provided; however, as a quick fix here's how I would add the one line of JavaScript,

1) Open the embeds/html_scripts template and add the following logic:

```
{if segment_2 == "my_page_url_title"}
   <!-- javascript here -->
{/if}
```

Note: Here's how segments are determined:

```
http://website.com/segment_1/segment_2/segment_3
```

Comment: Okay that last bit of code worked- sorta.  Now it is displaying the javascript map (the thing I'm trying to insert!) up at the top. But at least it's displaying it.  The problem I'm getting now is that it's still not reading my post and is acting like I "broke" the page. But at least it's displaying now!